# difference between _jspInit() and jspInit() in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

What is the difference between jspInit() and _jspInit()? I was able to override the jspInit() and it was invoked when the servlet is initialized. But _jspInit() was empty method and i couldn't able to override it. Why do we have two different versions for the same functionality? same with the jspDestroy?
JSP version is 2.2 with Tomcat 7

Update: 
PFB the jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%! public void jspInit(){
    System.out.println("In jspInit");
 }
 %>

<% System.out.println("Hello world"); %>
</body>
</html>
```

PFB the generated Servlet file.

```
public final class A_jsp extends org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent {

public void jspInit(){
   System.out.println("In jspInit");
}

 private static final javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory _jspxFactory =
      javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getDefaultFactory();

 private static java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long> _jspx_dependants;

 private volatile javax.el.ExpressionFactory _el_expressionfactory;
 private volatile org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager _jsp_instancemanager;

 public java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long> getDependants() {
  return _jspx_dependants;
 }

 public javax.el.ExpressionFactory _jsp_getExpressionFactory() {
   // some code
 }

 public org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager _jsp_getInstanceManager() {
  // some code
 }

 public void _jspInit() {
 }

 public void _jspDestroy() {
 }

 public void _jspService(final javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, final javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)
     throws java.io.IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException {
  // some code

 try {
  //some code

  out.write("\r\n");
  out.write("<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n");
  out.write("<html>\r\n");
  out.write("<body>\r\n");
  out.write("\r\n");
  out.write("\r\n");
  System.out.println("Hello world"); 
  out.write("\r\n");
  out.write("</body>\r\n");
  out.write("</html>");
 } catch (java.lang.Throwable t) {//some code
 } finally {
   _jspxFactory.releasePageContext(_jspx_page_context);
 }
}
```

}

Note: I have replaced some code with the comment. It has an empty _JspInit() and overriden jspInit(). I'm aware that i should not use `System.out` on server side code. It is for understanding purpose.

Comment: " _jspInit() was empty" mean in your code you have define it is as an empty body ? am i guess right ?

Comment: @vishalgajera No! in the generated Servlet the _jspinit() was empty. I have just overridden the jspInit(). I couldn't able to override the _jspInit().

Comment: please refer my answer

Answer (score 0):

The core differences:

`_jspInit()` method is generated by the container if any custom tags are used in the JSP. Otherwise it won't be generated.

If you try to override `_jspInit()` and using custom tags, container will throw compilation error saying -duplicate methods. (there will be two `_jspInit()` methods with same signature)

> The difference between overriding jspInit() and jspService() is that  - _jspService() will always be there in any JSP->java file and will take precedence and our jspService() method will not be used ever.
>
> But _jspInit() method appears in jsp->java file conditionally. so, our jspInit() method will be invoked when there is no _jspInit() method and this is quite possible.

Have a look at this nice [article](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/60627)

Answer (score -1):

Please correct me i'm wrong !!

When jsp page is translated into Servlet then jspinit() is converted into _jspinit() method.

Comment: we ca not access the service method of Generic Servlet. container always prefer the service() method of HttpServlet class and then decides which way to go either doget() or dopost() . as well destroy() can call and overridden